# edit/delete table with pop-up

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wanted to add edit & delete button inside table.on click of edit and delete buttons opens a popup where we can change the values and give update in pop-up, which will update in table in angular.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, you could for example place buttons in a table cell and implement necessary logic in the click event.

Full example with working delete button based on Angular Material documenation in this stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slhbob?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts

Here the crucial code snippets:

Adding Buttons in table row:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="onEdit(element)">Edit</button>
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="onDelete(element)">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Deleting elements from the data source:

```
onDelete(element: PeriodicElement): void {
    const indexToDelete = this.dataSource.findIndex(
      (periodicElement) => periodicElement.position === element.position
    );
    ELEMENT_DATA.splice(indexToDelete, 1);
    this.dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
    this.table.renderRows();
  }
```